# Learning of SVM Code

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Well its a forum for posting the question in which you feel difficulty , well the same thing happen to me so i post the question here , i need to learn the code , understand it , what its doing and what we can do more with it

```
// Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);


 // Set up training data
     float labels[4] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
     Mat labelsMat(3, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

     float trainingData[4][2] = { {501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}, {10, 501} };
     Mat trainingDataMat(3, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

     // Set up SVM’s parameters
     CvSVMParams params;
     params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
     params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
     params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

     // Train the SVM
     CvSVM SVM;
     SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

     Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
     // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
     for (int i = 0; i <2; ++i)
     for (int j = 0; j <2; ++j)
     {
     Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << i,j);
     float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

     if (response == 1)
     image.at<Vec3b>(j, i) = green;
     else if (response == -1)
     image.at<Vec3b>(j, i) = blue;
     }
```

I know this code is for training data , but i want to know about its basic things , its basic understanding , which i think i didn't found on opencv documentation like why and when we use `CV_8UC3` , and with which things this code is training

Thanks

Comment: btw, shouldn't it be `Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);` ? (4 data points, 4 labels)

Comment: @berak I don't know , i am just learning now , i didn't code on my own yet , thats why i am here for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` is an empty 3 channel matrix data, i.e. 512x512; R-G-B channels. At the end, this code draws the responses (predictions of SVM) onto that image - image at somewhere = green = (0,255,0). it is done in a for loop to create the lines from pointwise assigning.

the SVM model training is an internal process of [this method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train), in which opencv uses a learning algorithm that can be found only looking at the source code. however, it is declared and described in the documentation that the parameters like svm_type, kernel_type, k_fold, grid, balanced, ... changes the behaviour of the method.

Comment: why and when we use CV_8UC3 ?

Comment: `float labels[4] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};` what this line doing , can you explain your answer

Comment: 8U = unsigned 8 bits. It means every channel in a pixel can have 2^8 = 256 different values (0 to 255). A pixel having (255,0,0) for instance, means that BLUE = 255, GREEN = 0, RED = 0. He initialized zero image, so all pixels are zero = black. C3 means it has 3 channels, not 1. So it is not grayscale. It is colored. "labels" is just the labels of the training input. He wants to name the point (501,10) = 1 and the other points (255,10) (501,255) (10,501) = -1. After training, the points closer to (501,10) will be labeled "1" and shown with green, others will be blue.

Comment: Can i use the same approach for training my system on detecting vehicles ?

Comment: well, I don't know about your system. However I can give you info on SVM. It tries to classify the points according to a priori knowledge (labels here). For example, if you are using SIFT / SURF methods of opencv; after finding the keypoints, you can classify them with SVM, to group the closer points -as vehicle.

Comment: Yes i am using Surf method and now my next approach is to train it using SVM

Comment: `float trainingData[4][2] = { {501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}, {10, 501} };` here i have to use keypoints ?

Comment: to "train" SVM you need to supply these points. Then use the keypoints as test data. Please read the explanation. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html Learn "SVM" before learning the code. Good luck